# How to check whether phonegap is ready to use or not

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, dom-events, phonegap

As I am new to phonegap. I would like to know "how to check whether phonegap is ready to use or not". I created two folders "scripts and css" in www directory. I created common.js file in scripts folder. I written following code in common.js

```
var isPhoneGapReady = false; 
function init() { 
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady, false); 
var intervalID = window.setInterval(function() { 
if (PhoneGap.available) { 
onDeviceReady(); 
} 
}, 500); 
} 
function onDeviceReady() { 
window.clearInterval(intervalID); 
isPhoneGapReady = true; 
alert('The device is now ready'); 
} 
window.onload = init;
```

I am unable to know how to use this code in index.html. I using eclipse editor.

Helping hands are highly appreciated.

Comment: I appreciate people who helped me.

Comment: I have not got any answer for the question I asked.Please if you know the answer please help me.

Comment: Checkout [Apache Cordova API Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready). And again, before you post further questions, make sure that you accept some of the answers to your previous questions.